# Stop content jump due to ad refresh

Tags: html, jquery, css, adsense

I have Refresh ADS on sidebar every 30 seconds. The sidebar content is jumping – pls check on video - https://www.screencast.com/t/xCUxDrRx4BFf

Our different ads unit size is - 250250, 300250, 336*280

```
<style>
.aspect-ratio-box::before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 591.44px / 1127.34px * 100%;
}
.aspect-ratio-box::after { 
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
<div class="aspect-ratio-box">
 

<div style="border:1px solid black;width: 300px;">
<center><div id='xxxxxxxxxxx'>
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('xxxxxxxxxxx'); });
  </script>
  </div></center>
<br/>

<center><div id='xxxxxxxxxxx'>
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('xxxxxxxxxxx'); });
  </script>
  </div></center>
</div>
  </div>
```

Is there any way to fix the issue?

so sidebar content will not jumping.

Issue URL is - https://www.test2.guru99.com/software-testing.html

Comment: Have you tried using the `height` CSS property on the elements that contain the ads?

Comment: I have already to add on height element but every time to changes on ADS height value change.